# Anonymous Inner Type of Standard Java Classes in Content Assist? How are they used?

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist, anonymous-inner-class

I noticed that after updating to Java 8 SE with my Juno Eclipse Modeling Framework, my standard library objects started to point a new option of the methods as "Anonymous Inner Type" when Content Assist is called. I am trying to understand how these built-in options are used.

[image: a sample of how this appears in the IDE is shown in the image attached]

To my previous knowledge, anonymous inner class is a way to create an expression style, which in practicality used as a way to declare & instantiate a class in the same time. I rarely used this option but I recognized that most developers uses anonymous inner class types as a medium to write simpler and more readable code. Please correct me if I am wrong in any of these information about anonymous inner classes.

However, I am not sure how these anonymous types are started to appear in my Content Assist Panel and I couldn't find examples on how they are used. Since my practice with anonymous inner classes are limited, I would welcome any examples how these anonymous inner type Context Assist options are used.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want to know what this content assist option does, then select it, and you'll see. And then you'll be able to decide if this option is useful in this context, and/or if it could be useful in another context. If your question is "what is an anonymous class and when is it useful", then read the java tutorial about anonymous inner classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: - Basically what I am asking is how are these "Anonymous Inner Type" options on Standard Java Classes such as "Point" as displayed in the image used.
 - When I try to experiment with the option, nothing particular happened. 
-  Also, when I checked the issue from official site of Oracle and other tutorials and Google, I couldn't find anything related to the use of this type of(Such as in the image) Anonymous Inner Types. Yet, it was there as an option.
- Thus, if you know anything on the usage of these options, please share your information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor content assist for anonymous inner types is more useful for interfaces and abstract classes. For a concrete class such as `Point`, the only difference in content assist is

```
    Point point = new Point();
```

for an instance of the class itself, versus

```
    Point point = new Point() {
    };
```

for an instance of an anonymous inner type.

The nice thing with interfaces and abstract classes is that the anonymous inner class gets generated with method stubs

```
    Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }            
    };
```